# How to show menu dropdown above any div

Tags: html, css

I'm facing difficulties with some of the css. I've a menu items where I'm pops up a menu to rename, hide or delete it, I've included the css but its coming below the div present in the menu. I want it on top. Also I'm using bootstrap css.

Snippet:

```css
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.pagesmenu {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d3edff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #cde;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #2b5672;
  height: 39px;
  line-height: 39px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  width: 200px;
}
.pagesmenu.selected {
  background-color: #d3edff;
}
.portlet-body.form {
  background: #f0f3f5;
  padding: 10px;
}
.pageoption {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.dropdownpageopt {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdownpageopt a {
  color: black;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.dropdownpageopt a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.pageoption:hover .dropdownpageopt {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-body ui-sortable" id="nitspopupmenu">

  <div class="form-group ui-sortable-handle" id="div-1">
    <div class="pagesmenu"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Home<div class="pageoption"><a href="#" class="pageoptions"><img src="../nits-img/global/editor/portlet-config-icon.png"></a><div class="dropdownpageopt"><a href="#">Rename</a><a href="#">Hide</a><a href="#">Delete</a></div></div></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ui-sortable-handle" id="div-2">
    <div class="pagesmenu"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> About Us<div class="pageoption"><a href="#" class="pageoptions"><img src="../nits-img/global/editor/portlet-config-icon.png"></a><div class="dropdownpageopt"><a href="#">Rename</a><a href="#">Hide</a><a href="#">Delete</a></div></div></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ui-sortable-handle" id="div-3">
    <div class="pagesmenu"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Services<div class="pageoption"><a href="#" class="pageoptions"><img src="../nits-img/global/editor/portlet-config-icon.png"></a><div class="dropdownpageopt"><a href="#">Rename</a><a href="#">Hide</a><a href="#">Delete</a></div></div></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ui-sortable-handle" id="div-4">
    <div class="pagesmenu"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Our Team<div class="pageoption"><a href="#" class="pageoptions"><img src="../nits-img/global/editor/portlet-config-icon.png"></a><div class="dropdownpageopt"><a href="#">Rename</a><a href="#">Hide</a><a href="#">Delete</a></div></div></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ui-sortable-handle" id="div-5">
    <div class="pagesmenu"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Portfolio<div class="pageoption"><a href="#" class="pageoptions"><img src="../nits-img/global/editor/portlet-config-icon.png"></a><div class="dropdownpageopt"><a href="#">Rename</a><a href="#">Hide</a><a href="#">Delete</a></div></div></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ui-sortable-handle" id="div-6">
    <div class="pagesmenu"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Clients<div class="pageoption"><a href="#" class="pageoptions"><img src="../nits-img/global/editor/portlet-config-icon.png"></a><div class="dropdownpageopt"><a href="#">Rename</a><a href="#">Hide</a><a href="#">Delete</a></div></div></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ui-sortable-handle" id="div-7">
    <div class="pagesmenu"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Blog<div class="pageoption"><a href="#" class="pageoptions"><img src="../nits-img/global/editor/portlet-config-icon.png"></a><div class="dropdownpageopt"><a href="#">Rename</a><a href="#">Hide</a><a href="#">Delete</a></div></div></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ui-sortable-handle" id="div-8">
    <div class="pagesmenu"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Contact<div class="pageoption"><a href="#" class="pageoptions"><img src="../nits-img/global/editor/portlet-config-icon.png"></a><div class="dropdownpageopt"><a href="#">Rename</a><a href="#">Hide</a><a href="#">Delete</a></div></div></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/64egLfyr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying a higher z-index on the dropdown menu will do the trick.

```
.dropdownpageopt {
  z-index:1; // can make this higher if required. eg, 99
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.pagesmenu {
  position: inline-block;
  background-color: #d3edff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #cde;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #2b5672;
  height: 39px;
  line-height: 39px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Z-index on the whole .dropdownpageopt class instean on each link inside it,so the whole white box and the rest inside it can be on top, like this:

```
.dropdownpageopt {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

you can append z-index on your css code in section which include .dropdownpageopt class, example:

```
 .dropdownpageopt {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;   /*<-- this is needed to make z-index work*/
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     min-width: 100px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     margin-top: -30px;

     z-index: 99; /*<---this*/


  }
```

or in this section:

```
.pageoption:hover .dropdownpageopt {
    display: block;
    z-index: 99; /*<---this*/
}
```

the problem in your case is, Z-index only works on posiotioned element(i.e:absolute/fixed/relative), which you did'nt put in the link inside dropdownpageopt (it explained :[Here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)) . and even if you did and the z-index is works, it will only work for the link inside and the white box will stay not on top. so you need to put the z-index in whole dropdownpageopt class.

and the value does'nt necesarily have to be 99 or even 9999, i've tried 2 & 1 on .dropdownpageopt and it work.

-I hope this help.